# Image path not working correctly

Tags: html, css

In my main directory I created a folder called 'washingtondc'.  In this folder I put a folder called 'images' and an index.html file.  In the images folder is an image enter1.jpg.  I can't get the image to appear on my webpage.  Does anyone see why?

Here is the url that is working correctly:

http://yourfantasyfootballreality.com/washingtondc/index.html

here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>Washington DC 11/9/13<h1></center>
    <img src="washingtondc/images/enter1.jpg" width="147px" height="120px" alt=""/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Often it is the path. Try it without 'washingtondc' or use the absolute path to test... Another issue might be permissions, but a wrong path is usually the cause.

Comment: Could it be the invalid use of the width and height attributes?  They should be written as style="width:147px; height:120px;"

Comment: @Dan -- no ..width and height can be used in this manner .. ;)

Comment: tried this and it didn't work:  <img src="/images/enter1.jpg" width="147px" height="120px" alt=""/>

Comment: Using the "/" as first character in your path will default it to your root. Use it without the "/" to keep the relativity in the image url.

Comment: Don't put a slash before images!

Comment: Daniel- using the "width=" method, you shouldn't use "px".   @stackover - The url link helped partly, but what's the direct link to the image that you want to include?

Comment: Tried several scenarios to get the path to your image, but your server may be bugging you. I can't get the path to the image. Start looking at your htacces. I keep being directed to html pages.

Comment: @Dan - You are correct in that. An absolute path would be the full path with the domain. Ie [http://mydomain.com/path/to/my/image.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I named the images folder dcimages.  Sorry but thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be a problem with your server's configuration, maybe there is an `.htaccess` redirecting second level subfolders? I suppose this because trying to access your image: [enter1.jpg](http://yourfantasyfootballreality.com/washingtondc/images/enter1.jpg) loads your main site, as well as accessing [/images/](http://yourfantasyfootballreality.com/washingtondc/images/) folder. Check if your *images* folder has reading access.

Comment: I found the error.  I named the images folder dcimages :(  Sorry, but thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: That's it!, I'm glad you figured it out ;).

Answer (score 1):

As you have the images folder and index file in same folder, I think you just need is,

```
<img src="images/enter1.jpg" width="147px" height="120px" alt=""/>
```

Comment: @stackover could you please check the image path while using 'images/enter1.jpg' through inspector

Comment: @stackover You can inspect through your html elements and its attributes through inspectors available natively in web browsers. you can access it by right clicking on the respective element in window and select inspect element in most browsers. Or you can use extensions like Firebug in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the image extension is jpg or jpeg. Enter the src path accordingly.

Comment: This comment material. Use the comment section for that.